# Find page url with a function in my frame

Tags: javascript, url

I have made a html page and two website take it on her website like a frame.

I want to change the color of my frame. So i have to know witch website included my frame.

What function I have to use in javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  alert(window.top.location);
} catch (e) {
  alert("Couldn't read window.top.location.\n" + e.message);
}
```

This may not work due to cross-site policies. Alternately, you could have some server-side logic dynamically insert a stylesheet based on request parameters.

E.g.,

```
http://mysite.com/iframeContent?useStyles=http://yoursite.com/iframe.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into

```
window.frames
```

As that returns an array of frames within the current window.

This might also be of some help:

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/index.html?page=2#winoverview